# make :active work at the children node in IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9, pseudo-class

**HTML**:

```
<div class="productCss">
    <figure>
        <img src="pic/products/pullet00001.png" alt="this is a picture">
        <figcaption>some product word2</figcaption>
    </figure>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.productCss {
    border: black 1px solid;
}

.productCss:hover {
    border: blue 2px solid;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.productCss:active {
    border: blue 3px solid;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/RXW4W/)

This problem is only happened in IE.

When my cursor move in  and mouse press on the blank side, IE does work perfectly like other browsers.

However, if I mouse press on the  or  area, IE does not change the border as 3px as productCss:active written.

Can I solve this problem using css only?

Comment: have you tried adding `.productCss {width:100%;}`?

Comment: @kleinfreund you never know with IE. It's always worth a try, isn't it? By the way, I know that blocks should always be the full width, which is why I put this as a comment, not an answer.

Comment: For kleinfreund: I was testing by IE9.
For joeytje50: I tried, but useless.
IE is always a problem maker for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Case 1: The `.productCss` is clicked on the edge**

- it works in IE and other browser. The `:active` state is true

**Case 2: The `figure` is clicked**

For emphasis we set `figure { border: 1px solid red; }`

- it works in other browsers. The `:active` state is true
- it doesn't work in IE.

Why is this? I guess IE acts as follows: We don't click the `.productCss`, but the `figure`. Therefor only the `figure` has the `:active` state, not the parent div.

Comment: Agree, It seems :active in css in IE does not perform the Event Bubbling like javascript does.

Comment: hmm...since there are 2 days passed and no one answer this problem, I think this can only be solved by javascript....